# Is there an idiomatic expression for a situation wherein junior employees get paid more than their senior colleagues?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a term or idiomatic expression or phrase that describes a situation wherein junior employees get paid more than their senior colleagues.

Comment: If employee age is involved, and not just seniority of employment,, then *ageism*.

Answer (score 7):

This is called ***pay*** or [***salary inversion***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salary_inversion) (see Wikipedia in link; sometimes also called *inverted pay* or *an inverted pay scale*). It typically happens when it costs more to hire someone new than what existing employees are being paid, though it could potentially also occur if someone junior is given a large raise for some reason. You can find articles about it on the web, like [this one from *MBA Skool*](http://www.mbaskool.com/business-articles/human-resource/4757-how-to-deal-with-pay-inversion.html).